# Processing ActiveMQ Messages with Apache Camel and JAVA

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a problem receiving AMQ-Messages in a JAVA-Method. I'm routing with a Camel-Route in Spring DSL like this:

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="activemq:foo.bar?maxConcurrentConsumers=1"/>
    <camel:to uri="bean:fooService?method=handleBarEvent"/>
</camel:route>
```

My JAVA-Code looks like:

```
package my.company.service

import org.apache.activemq.Message;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FooService {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FooService.class);

    public void handleBarEvent(Message in) {
        LOG.info(in);
    }

    public void handleOtherEvent(Message in) {
        LOG.info(in);
    }
}
```

Now if I put a `String`-based Message into the AMQ, I get the following Error from Camel:

```
org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException: Ambiguous method invocations possible: [
  public void my.company.service.FooService.handleBarEvent(org.apache.activemq.Message),
  public void my.company.service.FooService.handleOtherEvent(org.apache.activemq.Message)
]
```

Why is Camel not calling the defined `handleBarEvent`-Method?

What type must the Method accept as input to get the whole AMQ-Message?

I tried to change the Method to `public void handleBarEvent(Object in)` but then the Method just gets the `String`-Body, without the Message-Headers.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `Exchange`-Class as the parameter `handleBarEvent(Exchange exchange)` and Camel will pass the full message/headers as expected...

- `exchange.getIn().getBody()` to get the message body
- `exchange.getIn().getHeader([headerName])` to get a header value, etc

also, you can use [bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) in more explicit ways to bind body/headers to parameters directly like this...

```
public String hello(String name, @Header("country") String country) {
    return "Hello " + name + " you are from " + country;
}
```

Comment: Passing the Exchange to the Method works fine! Thank you very much